# Order Number missing in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

In my site, I am passing multiple items to cart using Paypal. The price ,product name everything appearing correctly. But the order number not displaying in the Paypal. I have pasted my code below.

```
<form name=pay_last_form method=post action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'>
<input type=hidden name=cmd value=_cart>
<input type=hidden name=upload value='1'>
<input type=hidden name=rm value='2'>
<input type=hidden name=business value=mymail_id>
<input type=hidden name=item_name_1 value='Deep House 01 - Download Version'>
<input type=hidden name=amount_1 value='14.96'>
<input type=hidden name=item_number_1 value='1'>
<input type=hidden name=shipping value=''>
<input type=hidden name=currency_code value='EUR'>
<input type=hidden name=custom value='17297'>
<input type=hidden name=return value='thanks-payment.php'>
<input type=hidden name=cancel_return value='payment-cancel.php'>
<input type=hidden name=notify_url value='success_payment.php'>
</form>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to the order number as your item number?  And where are you specifically referring to it not showing up at, on the checkout page, in the transaction details, or etc?

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad I am referring my order number in custom input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you expecting to see your custom value at?  This will not show on the payment page, as this is a pass thru variable that the merchant will only see.  You should see it in the transaction details, when you log into the merchant account.  If you check the transaction details in the buyer account, you will not see it.  This is also sent back thru IPN as well.  This is working how it should.  I also just ran a test and it is showing where it should be showing.  If you are trying to get it to show on the payment page, you would need to use a different variable, one that is designed to show up for the buyer.

Comment: Can you please say the variable name that is designed to show the value to buyer in Paypal widget

Comment: If you are wanting the information to show on the payment page, you would need to either use item_name_x, item_number_x, or use one of the optional variables such as onx_x that can be used with items.

Answer (score 0):

Best to go live for final testing once you have established that your code works. Try using $1 transactions.

Try sending "item_number" and not "item_number_1". Also, try adding a few ore digits to make it look real.

You can retrieve it as Request("item_number")